# Order one file based on the order of another file. Both files contain a Header row

Tags: unix

I have two files that I want to later on compare.  Both files contain in the first row the headings.  Both files are generated from different tools.  Because they are created by different tools, the column order does not match between the two files.  I want to order the columns of one file to match the order of the columns of another file.  I want to do this in unix. Both files use a pipe as a delimiter.

Example:

File 1:

```
Userid|Account|Name|Dept
jonsa1|6532158|Sally|A42
```

File 2:

```
Name|Dept|Account|Userid
Sally|B64|6532158|jonsa1
```

I want to reorder the columns (and data) of File 2 to match File 1:

File 2:

```
Userid|Account|Name|Dept
jonsa1|6532158|Sally|B64
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `csvcut` from the [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to reorder the columns, and `sed` to extract the header from the first file and turn the pipes into commas so the names are in the right format for the `-c` (columns) option:

```sh
$ csvcut -d '|' -c "$(sed '1{s/|/,/g;q}' file1)" file2 | csvformat -D '|'
Userid|Account|Name|Dept
jonsa1value1|6532158|Sally|B64
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, unfortunately we don't have csvkit package installed on our servers.

Comment: So install it. Really useful programs in it.

Comment: I'm an enduser, I do not have admin privileges on the Linux servers.